# iptables always needs restart

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I have a CentOS 7 PC, on which I'm using iptables.

I have an Oracle 11gR2 instance on that PC and I need to access is from other PCs in the LAN.

My `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov  3 11:25:41 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [296:52711]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1158 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2809 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5061 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9633 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9401 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9403 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9402 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7276 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7286 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5558 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5578 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1414 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1158 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9043 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2809 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5061 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9633 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9401 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9403 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9402 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7276 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7286 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5558 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov  3 11:25:41 2014
```

The oracle line is:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
```

The bad thing is that after reboot in order to make it work I always have to use

```
sudo service iptables restart
```

If I don't restart iptables manually, it doesn't open 1521 for incoming connections.

Is there a way to tell iptables not to "forget" what's written inside its file?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the iptables file, all the configurations stay in memory and to persist through a system reboot you need to save it using the command bellow:

**iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables**

Comment: I get "Access denied" when executing this command. Same thing with sudo.

Comment: Try this command then: "sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save"

Comment: This has no effect. It saves the same iptables file and does not reload it at boot

Comment: Well, you could use the command "/sbin/service iptables save". Since you are using CentOS 7, I would recommend you looking at FirewallD, that comes with this version.

Comment: If that doesnt work, could you check if you are using the Minimal version?